# Found inside a baseboard heater. Is this mold?

Tags: mold, baseboard

is a picture of something i spotted on the aluminum/steel/metal protector inside a baseboard heater.  No smell.[image]

Comment: To tell if it is mold, you must send it for testing.  Dirt/dust/bad cleaning and mold look almost the same in pictures/real life.

Comment: I agree with crip659. Furthermore, does it matter? Clean it up with a bleach solution and go on with life. Mold isn't phosgene gas. It's always everywhere.

Comment: @isherwood thank you for your replies. i'm just glad isn't circular/spore looking.

Answer (score 3):

Fungal spores are everywhere. You are breathing them right now. They are not harmful.

The picture looks like the normal dirt that accumulates behind baseboards.

Get an old spray bottle and fill it with water and add a few mL of 5% sodium hypochlorite a.k.a. household bleach. Spray and wipe.